# What is a stochastic differential equation of the form $dZ = f(Z_{prev}, X_{prev})dt + CdW_t$ called?

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, matlab, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

At every time step I can approximate the change in $Z$ using the following equation:

$$ dZ = f(Z_{prev}, X_{prev})dt + CdW_t, \quad(1)$$

$$dW_t = r\sqrt{dt}$$

where $C$ is some constant, and $r$ is a normally distributed value. Based on this I will have a guess for $Z_{next}$:
$$ Z_{next} = Z_{prev} + dZ$$

I ask because I am interested in writing a simple MATLAB solver for this type of an SDE, based on the algorithm I outlined above. However, I am not sure if the algorithm makes sense, and I am having trouble searching for resources to answer this question because I am not sure what to call an SDE of the form presented in equation $(1)$.

Most SDE solution schemes e.g. Euler-Mauryama assume an SDE of the form:

$$ dZ = f(Z_{prev})dt + gZ_{prev}dW_t$$

but my $dW_t$ term does not depend on $Z_{prev}$.

Comment: Your equations seem to confound math (SDEs) with code (or recurrence relations). If the diffusion function is constant (i.e., not a function of state variable) then you have "additive noise" (rather than multiplicative noise in your example). Euler-Maruyama doesn't care what the noise term is (it may be less efficient for more complex noise). Common additive noise stochastic processes are [Brownian motion, a.k.a. Wiener Process with drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Related_processes) and  [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck / HMV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck_process).

Comment: It doesn't depend on $Z_{prev}$, but it can be written as a function of it without using it. We do this all the time when we use code which is more general than the application that we have in mind. Consider numerically solving $y'=y$ with ode45; the function handle expected by ode45 takes both a $t$ and a $y$ argument, even though in this case you do not use the $t$ argument.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of a resource see the online book  [Applied Stochastic Differential Equations](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Easolin/sde-book/sde-book.pdf).

Indeed as mentioned in the comments, the method simplifies in your case since the volatility coefficient doesn't depend on $Z$. For the SDE

$$dZ=f(Z,t)dt+L(Z,t)d\beta$$
following the online book  [Applied Stochastic Differential Equations](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Easolin/sde-book/sde-book.pdf) pg .132, we have

$$Z(t_{k+1})=Z(t_{k})+f(Z(t_{k}),t_{k})\Delta t+L(Z(t_{k}),t_{k})\Delta \beta_{k}$$

and so in your case

$$Z(t_{k+1})=Z(t_{k})+f(Z(t_{k}),t_{k})\Delta t+C\Delta \beta_{k},$$

as you mentioned for random variable $\Delta \beta_{k}\sim N(0,\Delta t)$.